# How do I use a standalone class in cakephp 1.3?

Tags: php, class, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a standalone class I wrote in PHP for some very basic LDAP/AD functions. and I would like to use this class in a project I am working on in cakephp.

It looks like in cakephp 1.2 I could just add the class as a vendor, however it looks like cakephp 1.3 removed support for vendors. So how would I go about calling a few function from this class?

(I'd like to try to keep the class itself the same and not turn it into a plugin, as that seems unnecessary)

Thanks!

code below:

```
**<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

var $name = 'Users';

    //commented out because it breaks the script
    //App::import('Lib', 'ldap');


function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}

    function login() {

        if (!empty($this->data)) {
                if ($ldap->auth($this->data['User']['user'],$this->data['User']['password'])) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
                        $this->Session->write('user', $this->data['User']['user']);
                        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login Failed', true));
                }
        }
    }

    function logout() {
        $this->Session->delete('user');
        $this->redirect($this->referer());

    }

function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid user', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
}

function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    $projects = $this->User->Project->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('projects'));
}

function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid user', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        }
    }
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    }
    $projects = $this->User->Project->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('projects'));
}

function delete($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for user', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted', true));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
}
?>**
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cake 1.3 still perfectly supports the idea of vendor files. In addition, they [now also support  "libraries"](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1579/Library-classes), additional classes that are not 3rd party classes. Just pop your files into the `/vendors` or `/libs` directory and load the file using `App::import`.

Comment: I put my ldap.php in the libs folder and put "App::import('Lib', 'ldap');" in my users_controller.php, but when I call any page I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetracker\controllers\users_controller.php on line 6"

Comment: @mrlanrat Well, you have a **syntax error** somewhere, which doesn't have anything to do with Cake's libs or vendors.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working, I had to call "App::import('Lib', 'ldap');" outside of the controller class and then call it as a new class inside the function I wanted.

Below is the end result

```
<?php
App::import('Lib', 'ldap');
class UsersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Users';

    function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }

        function login() {

            if (!empty($this->data)) {
                $ldap = new ldap;
                    if ($ldap->auth($this->data['User']['user'],$this->data['User']['password'])) {

                            if (!$this->User->findByUser($this->data['User']['user']) )
                            {
                                $ldap_info = $ldap->getInfo($this->data['User']['user']);
                                $this->data['User']['name'] = $ldap_info['name'];
                                $this->add();
                            }

                            $this->Session->write('user', $this->data['User']['user']);
                            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                    } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Login Failed', true));
                    }
            }
        }

        function logout() {
            $this->Session->delete('user');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());

        }

    function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid user', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id));
    }

    private function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        $projects = $this->User->Project->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('projects'));
    }

    function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$id && empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid user', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        if (!empty($this->data)) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }
        $projects = $this->User->Project->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('projects'));
    }

    function delete($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for user', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('User deleted', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('User was not deleted', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
?>
```